# Use of three tenses in one sentence

Tags: tense

It seems to me that I needed to use three different tenses in this sentence - is that correct?

I **will look** at Elsa’s perception of the literal confinement of Nieu Bethesda that **caused** the town people **to be figuratively confined** to the previous century.

I read through the suggested questions, and I see that I can use different tenses in one sentence. I guess my question is - did I do it correctly?

Comment: Technically you've only got two tenses in the sentence. 1) *will look* is 'future' (even more technically, non-past with future reference) 2) *caused* is past. 3) *to be confined* is a passive infinitive--it has no tense. In any case, it's fine.

Comment: "passive infinitive" - this is above my level of understanding at this point in time. Thank you for mentioning it - I will have to research it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence is absolutely correct.  You are talking about doing something in the future about something that happened in the past that relates to another action.  So, you need all of the tenses exactly as you have them.

Answer (score 0):

As with any language, you use verb tense to convey information.  If the information spans multiple time frames, then you will use multiple tenses.  Example:

> The boss **is saying** that the board **met** last week **to decide** what **will be** the quotas for next fiscal quarter.

I'm sure this is not much different from your own language.

Your sentence is correct, although I'm not sure I would say "figuratively confined to the last century," -- but now we're getting into writing style and metaphor, which is about personal choice and not grammar.

Comment: Until my English gets better, I want to steer clear of 'personal choice'. Will you be able to help me make it read better, and still keep the meaning? I want to convey the meaning that the location of the town (deep rural) is what cause it to be so conservative.

Comment: @Susan the common metaphor for something like this is to be "stuck" (in some way) in old patterns or traditions or habits.  *Mired* is a nice word, as it conveys the image of being stuck in a muddy swamp, eg: *"They were **mired** in the previous century."*  But "confined" might work, if someone is *forcing* them to stick with old customs.